# Create new branch from specific commit onwards

Tags: git, version-control, branch, commit, git-commit

I want to create a new branch, starting from a certain commit. However, I want all the commits that were commited afterwards to be part of that branch too.

Lets assume this is `branch-D` with all the commits.

```
> branch-D
commit-A ---- commit-B ---- commit-C ---- commit-D
```

I want to remove everything from `commit-B` to a new `branch`, lets name it `branch-C`, and only keep `commit-A` on `branch-D`

```
> branch-D
commit-A

> branch-C
commit-B ---- commit-C ---- commit-D
```

I haven't pushed anything to a remote repository yet. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which commit is the initial commit? Do you want to make `branch-C` based on the parent of `commit-A` or make `branch-C` as an orphan branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** - I misread your diagrams and had mixed up the branch names as a result.  Also as torek points out, a "more correct" reading of your diagrams includes some ambiguities.  I'll keep my answer mostly as is (but with branch names straightened out) as I believe it conveys the main principles; and I'll at a bit about using rebase if you need to further edit `branchC` history; but for a more detailed answer, see torek's response.

---

First let me get to the solution I think you're looking for; but I suggest reading beyond that, because there's conceptual confusion in this question that would be worth clearing up.

So you have now

```
A -- B -- C -- D <--(branchD)
```

I think you want to end up with *only* `A` on `branchD`, and a new branch for `B`, `C`, and `D`.  So step one is, with `branchD` (or `D`) checked out, create the new branch

```
git branch branchC
```

Then move the `branchD` branch back to `A`.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

(I used `HEAD~3` because in this example, that would be one name for `A`.  It depends on the number of commits being taken out of `master`'s history.  It would always be ok to use the commit ID (SHA) of `A` in place of `HEAD~3`.)

After these steps, you have

```
A <--(branchD)
 \
  B -- C -- D <--(branchC)
```

which *looks like* what you described, but we didn't get there the way the description implied.

I didn't move commits; I moved branches.  This is much more straightforward in git, and it reflects that commits do not "belong to" branches in git the way they do in some systems.  Consequently the statement "branch at a previous commit but include the following commits on that branch" doesn't *really* make sense in git.

The ambiguities in the before-and-after diagrams in the question do leave open the possibility that I've misunderstood exactly what `branchC` should include in its history.  If `branchC` is *not* meant to include `A`, then you have to rewrite `B`, `C`, and `D` - and you can most easily do that with `git rebase -i`.  After creating `branchC` and moving `branchD` you could say

```
git rebase -i branchD^ branchC
```

Here `branchD^` is a possible name for "the commit before `A`.  If there is such a commit, it may have other names - perhaps `master`, or certainly its commit ID.  If there is *no* such commit, then I suppose you could say

```
git rebase -i --root branchC
```

(but in that scenario, trying to remove `A` from the `branchC` history probably makes no sense, so I doubt that's the what's going on here).

The rebase command will bring up a text editor with a TODO list with an entry for each commit. You can delete the entry for commit `A` from the list, then save and exit.  This won't disturb `branchD` - it will still point at `A` - but it will create a new history for `branchC` by copying `B`, `C`, and `D`.  so then you would have

```
x -- B' -- C' -- D' <--(branchC)
  \
   A <--(branchD)
```

In any event, to do what you want means removing `B`, `C`, and `D` from the history of `branchD`.  You mentioned that these commits have not been `push`ed, so it should be no problem; but that is an important distinction to keep in mind.  Any time you want to remove a commit from a branch's history, it's easier to do if the branch on the remote doesn't yet know about the commits in question.

Answer (score 5):

The peculiar thing about Git is that branch *names* don't affect what's in your *commit history*, except that they let you—and anyone else, which is very important—*find* the commits.  The secret is that in Git, a commit is, potentially, on *many* branches *at the same time*.

Importantly, though, no commit, once it is made, can ever be *changed*.  It can be *copied* to a (new, slightly different) commit, but it can't be changed.

Also, while any branch name *can* be forced to point to any commit, there's a "normal direction" for branch-name motion: normally, they only *advance*.  Advancing, as we'll see in a moment, means that whatever commit they used to point to, is still "on" that branch.  So once you've given your commits to someone else—some other Git—and asked them to call those commits `branch-D`, it's hard to get the *other* Git to retract that.  Hence:

> I haven't pushed anything to a remote repository yet. Is there a way to do this?

Yes, and there may be a very easy way: the "haven't pushed anything yet" means that you're the *only one* who has these commits, so however you find them, that's how *everyone* finds them, because you're "everyone". :-)  There's no need to get anyone else to change anything.

As long as they're already laid out the way you want, you just need to rearrange the way in which you find these commits.

Let's draw your existing series of commits the "Git Way":

```
... <--A <--B <--C <--D   <-- branch-D
```

In Git, each commit is uniquely identified by its hash ID.  These things are big and ugly and apparently-random (though they're actually completely deterministic), so we hardly ever use them, or use an abbreviated form like `d1c9d3a`.  Instead of that, let's just call the last commit `D`.

Inside commit `D`, there's another hash ID, identifying `D`'s *parent commit*.  Let's say it's `c033bae`, but let's just call that "commit `C`".  So we say that `D` *points to* `C`.

Similarly, `C` points back to `B`, which points back to `A`, which points back to ... well, perhaps the tip commit of `master`—you didn't say, but let's assume that for now:

```
...--o--o   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C--D   <-- branch-D
```

This is a more compact way to draw them.  Commits always, necessarily, point *backwards*, so we don't really need the internal arrows—we know they always go backwards.  Branch *names*, however, like `master` and `branch-D` ... well, we can make those point *anywhere*.  What we want to do is to make them point to the "tip commit" of a branch.

Git finds commits by starting from the one that the branch-name points to: `D`, for `branch-D`, or the final `o` on the first row for `master`.  Then it looks at the parent of the current commit, to move backwards.  Then it looks at the parent's parent, and so on.  Hence the two `o` commits are on both `master` *and* `branch-D`: we can find them by starting from `master`, or we can find them by starting from `branch-D` and working backwards four steps.

This means that the picture we *want* looks, maybe, like this:

```
...--o--o   <-- master
         \
          A   <-- branch-D
           \
            B--C--D   <-- branch-C
```

Here, the commits that are on `master` are also on both branches, and commit `A`, which now is the tip of `branch-D`, is still on `branch-C` as well.  It's just not the *tip* of `branch-C` any more.

---

On the other hand, perhaps the picture we want looks like this:

```
          ?--?--?   <-- branch-C
         /
...--o--o   <-- master
         \
          A   <-- branch-D
           \
            B--C--D   <-- ???
```

That is, we need to answer a question.  The name `branch-C` will point to some particular commit.  When we go three steps back, should we arrive at commit `A`?  Or should we arrive instead at the last commit on `master`?

---

If the first picture is the right one, the answer is easy: make the new name, `branch-C`, pointing to commit `D`; then force the existing name `branch-D` to move back to commit `A`.  To do this:

```
git branch branch-C branch-D  # copy the hash ID from branch-D to new branch-C
```

and then, depending on which branch is checked out right now, either:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-A> # move current branch; re-set index and work-tree
```

or:

```
git branch -f branch-D <hash-of-A> # force branch-D to point to A
```

Note that before using `git reset --hard`, it's a very good idea to make sure that you have nothing modified that you want to save.  While *commits* are pretty much permanent (you can get them back, typically for at least 30 days, even if you kick them off all branch names), the index and work-tree that `git reset --hard` clobbers are *not*.

If you want that second picture, though—if you want the parent of commit `B` to be something other than commit `A`—you'll have to *copy* commit `B` to a new, different commit, that's "like `B`, but...".  The differences between the original `B` and the copy will include the changed parent hash ID.

For *that*, you will need to use `git cherry-pick` or an equivalent (such as `git rebase`, which is basically an en-masse cherry-pick operation that copies lots of commits).  To do that, you could:

```
git checkout -b branch-C master
```

giving:

```
...--o--o   <-- branch-C (HEAD), master
         \
          A--B--C--D   <-- branch-D
```

and then run three `git cherry-pick` commands to copy `B`, `C`, and `D`; or simpler—this uses the `<commit>~<number>` notation:

```
 git cherry-pick branch-D~3..branch-D
```

to copy all three at once.  This produces:

```
          B'-C'-D'   <-- branch-C (HEAD)
         /
...--o--o   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C--D   <-- branch-D
```

At this point, it's safe to force `branch-D` to point to commit `A`:

```
git branch -f branch-D branch-D~3
```

You can do this by hash IDs, as in the earlier examples, too:

```
git branch -f branch-D <hash-of-A>
```

All we're doing with `branch-D~3` is telling Git: *count back three parent steps, one parent at a time*.  So we start at `D`, count back one step to `C`, count back another step to `B`, and count back a third step to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
git checkout hashOfCommitA
```

then

```
git checkout -b NewBranchName
```

now You have new branch with commit A. Then You can go back to commit D

```
git checkout nameOfFirstBranch
```

and then revert commit A from this branch

```
git revert hashOfCommitA
```

now You have to branches on one of them there is only commit A while on the other are commits b,c and d.

Answer (score -1):

The most straight forward way to do this would be to create 2 new branches off the commit prior to commit-A. Then cherry-pick commit-A to 1 branch and cherry-pick commits B,C,D to 2nd branch.

Comment: This is not the most straightforward way. Moving the refs is actually much easier.  Cherry-picking is easily the most over-recommended git operation on Stack Overflow; it's good for a specific use case (which I'm happy to have never encountered in my own work) but everyone wants to rush to it for things that can be more easily done (and with fewer side-effects) with other commands.